# Click in all buttons with same classname

Tags: javascript, console

I want to create a script that clicks on all buttons with the className download-invoice but I would like this to happen using async await. At the moment I can only do without it, then some clicks are ignored. What should I do?

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("download-invoice")
for (i=0;i<buttons.length;i++){
    buttons[i].click()
}
```

Comment: What does clicking this button do? Is it triggering one of your functions?

Comment: @JeremyThille The click performs the download function

Comment: Ah, so you want to click each ownload button one after the other, with a delay? Did you try with `setTimeout` ?

Comment: It was not effective